# Jquery failing to pass variable to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to pass variables from javascript to a php where it can execute somethings , but the php file is not being called or not being executed , and ive checked , the php file works properly on its own.

```
$(function () {
   $('#comments').click(function () {
     var data1 = '4';
     var data2 = yes;
     var data3 = '26';
     $.post('new.php', 'val=' + data1, function (response) {
       alert(response);
     });
     return false;
   });
 }); 

<div id='comments'>
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething();" >Click Me!</a></div>
```

Could someone please point out the mistake ive done :)

Cheers

Comment: What's "yes"? Do you mean "true"?

Comment: have you ckecked about the url directory php file?

Comment: How did you determine that PHP is not called? Did you check the Network tab in your browser's developer tools? Did it cause 404 perhaps? You could add an error handler and find out as well.

Comment: how to check it jack....could u give me some assistance plz.....

Answer (score 2):

From the snippet you've posted the main problem is that you're referencing an undeclared variable, `yes`.
Maybe you intended to write `true`. JavaScript boolean values are just `true`, and `false`.

Also `doSomething` appears to be undeclared, but in this case since you're already handling this in the JS code `$('#comments').click()`,
you should remove the `onClick` listener from the element.

Answer (score 1):

Change your ajax post data settings. Try below code

```
 $.post('new.php', {val:data1}, function (response) {


  });
```

See examples at **[jQuery POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)**